# Getting multiple result sets from database and translating result sets to required class properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to retrieve multiple result sets from DB using entity framework. I got this implementation in MSDN but i want to make it generic.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/advanced/multiple-result-sets

My generic class will contain all the list objects required for translating from result sets. Like for two result sets `Blogs` and `posts` my class will be :

```
public class ContainerClass
{
   public List<Blogs> blogs { get; set; }
   public List<Posts> posts { get; set; }
}
```

I have modified the code as below and stuck at translating result sets to respective class.

```
public T GetMultipleDataset<T>() where T : new() {

            T dataSets = new T();

            int Count = 0;

            var t = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(a => a.PropertyType.IsGenericType && a.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>));

            Dictionary<string, string> types = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (var p in t) {
                var listObjectName = p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name;
                var propertyName = p.Name;

                types.Add(listObjectName, propertyName);
            }

            // Create a SQL command to execute the stored procedure
            var cmd = _dbContext.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetAllBlogsAndPosts]";

            try {

                _dbContext.Database.Connection.Open();
                // Run the stored procedure
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                do {

                    Type typ = dataSets.GetType().GetProperty(types.ElementAt(Count).Value).GetType();

                    var p = typ.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { typ });

                    var o = Activator.CreateInstance(p);

                    // Read Blogs from the first result set
                    var blogs = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_dbContext)
                        .ObjectContext
                        .Translate<>(reader, types.ElementAt(Count).Value, MergeOption.AppendOnly);  //stuck here

                    // Move to second result set and read Posts
                    reader.NextResult();
                    Count++;

                } while (reader != null);
            }
            finally {
                _dbContext.Database.Connection.Close();
            }

            return dataSets;
        }
```

I want to translate result set to respective Blogs and Posts of ContainerClass. Is it possible ?

Comment: SO you get back a list of possible values from EntityFrameowrk and you want to convert to your specific type?

Comment: yes. multiple list of possible values which i want to map to relevant lists in my ContainerClass. Edited Question.